# How to implement multiple thread pools in a Play application using cats-effect IO

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-cats, playframework-2.6, cats-effect

In my Play application, I service my requests usings `cats-effect`'s `IO`, instead of `Future` in the controller, like this (super-simplified):

```
def handleServiceResult(serviceResult: ServiceResult): Result = ...

def serviceMyRequest(request: Request): IO[ServiceResult] = ...

def myAction = Action { request =>
  handleServiceResult(
    serviceMyRequest(request).unsafeRunSync()
  )
}
```

Requests are then processed (asynchronously) on Play's default thread pool. Now, I want to implement multiple thread pools to handle different sorts of requests. Were I using `Future`s, I could do this:

```
val myCustomExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = ...

def serviceMyRequest(request: Request): Future[ServiceResult] = ...

def myAction = Action.async { request =>
  Future(serviceMyRequest(request))(myCustomExecutionContext)
    .map(handleServiceResult)(defaultExecutionContext)
}
```

But I'm not using `Future`s, I'm using `IO`, and I'm not sure about the right way to go about implementing it. This looks promising, but seems a bit clunky:

```
def serviceMyRequest(request: Request): IO[ServiceResult] = ...

def myAction = Action { request =>
  val ioServiceResult = for {
    _ <- IO.shift(myCustomExecutionContext)
    serviceResult <- serviceMyRequest(request)
    _ <- IO.shift(defaultExecutionContext)
  } yield {
    serviceResult
  }
  handleServiceResult(ioServiceResult.unsafeRunSync())
}
```

Is this the right way to implement it? Is there a best practice here? Am I screwing up badly? Thanks.

Comment: I have a suspicion that Play isn't going to work well with cats-effect. The fundamental atom of concurrency is different in those two libraries. If you want to build an effect-free web service, you might consider http4s.

Comment: That said, there are a lot of shims between `IO[_]` and `Future[_]`, so you _could_ make it work.

Comment: @erip I want to use http4s on my next project... but for now I'm stuck with Play. Yeah I've looked at `unsafeToFuture` for example, but I don't believe there's room for an `ExecutionContext` there. For what it's worth, the Play/IO application has worked amazingly well so far... just need to slide a shim into this boundary, like you said.

Comment: Ok, at this point I'm reasonably certain that my somewhat clunky solution is the way to go, and that I should just abstract it out to make it pretty.

Comment: If you shift like you do in this for-comprehension, you might end up staying in the `customExecutionContext` if the `serviceMyRequest` throws an exception. You might want to use `bracket` to make sure you shift back in any case.

Comment: @rethab good point, thanks. I updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so since this doesn't seem to be well-trodden ground, this is what I ended up implementing:

```
trait PlayIO { self: BaseControllerHelpers =>

  implicit class IOActionBuilder[A](actionBuilder: ActionBuilder[Request, A]) {

    def io(block: Request[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      actionBuilder.apply(block.andThen(_.unsafeRunSync()))
    }

    def io(executionContext: ExecutionContext)(block: Request[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      val shiftedBlock = block.andThen(IO.shift(executionContext) *> _ <* IO.shift(defaultExecutionContext))
      actionBuilder.apply(shiftedBlock.andThen(_.unsafeRunSync()))
    }

  }

}
```

Then (using the framework from the question) if I mix `PlayIO` into the controller, I can do this,

```
val myCustomExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = ...

def handleServiceResult(serviceResult: ServiceResult): Result = ...

def serviceMyRequest(request: Request): IO[ServiceResult] = ...

def myAction = Action.io(myCustomExecutionContext) { request =>
  serviceMyRequest(request).map(handleServiceResult)
}
```

such that I execute the action's code block on `myCustomExecutionContext` and then, once complete, thread-shift back to Play's default execution context.

**Update:**

This is a bit more flexible:

```
trait PlayIO { self: BaseControllerHelpers =>

  implicit class IOActionBuilder[R[_], A](actionBuilder: ActionBuilder[R, A]) {

    def io(block: R[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      actionBuilder.apply(block.andThen(_.unsafeRunSync()))
    }

    def io(executionContext: ExecutionContext)(block: R[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      if (executionContext == defaultExecutionContext) io(block) else {
        val shiftedBlock = block.andThen(IO.shift(executionContext) *> _ <* IO.shift(defaultExecutionContext))
        io(shiftedBlock)
      }
    }

  }

}
```

**Update2:**

Per the comment above, this will ensure we always shift back to the default thread pool:

```
trait PlayIO { self: BaseControllerHelpers =>

  implicit class IOActionBuilder[R[_], A](actionBuilder: ActionBuilder[R, A]) {

    def io(block: R[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      actionBuilder.apply(block.andThen(_.unsafeRunSync()))
    }

    def io(executionContext: ExecutionContext)(block: R[A] => IO[Result]): Action[A] = {
      if (executionContext == defaultExecutionContext) io(block) else {
        val shiftedBlock = block.andThen { ioResult =>
          IO.shift(executionContext).bracket(_ => ioResult)(_ => IO.shift(defaultExecutionContext))
        }
        io(shiftedBlock)
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I was looking for a good way to execute `unsafeRunSync` instead of managing a `Future`.